# How secure is module-info.java?

Tags: java-9, java-module

I'm just thinking how secure is the module-info.java , for example lets say if the library provider has added some restriction and opens only few service classes for the consumers.

I believe the consumer can easily remove this enforced restriction by just decompiling the module-info.class, do the changes to remove the restriction and patch it on the provided library jar to access the restricted packages/classes.

Let me know if I'm missing something , not sure if there are other checks added on v9 onward for the security , on previous versions we can easily patch a single class on the jar.

Thanks
Abdul

Comment: You don't even need to decompile anything. At least with OpenJDK-based implementations of Java, you can simply compile and/or run your application with `--add-exports`  / `--add-opens` to gain access to classes in certain packages. But even more simply, they can just run the application on the class-path so that the module-info descriptor is ignored. Also, since you mention patching, there's `--patch-module` as well.

Comment: In short, Java language artifacts are not security features.